# How to check which user is making calls to the API while testing using SpringBoot mocikto and junit4

Tags: java, junit, spring-security, mockito

I am testing few classes  using Junit4 and mockito , while calling an API i am getting an authentication error , so i just wanted to know , how can i find out which user is making an call to an API , as  i want ADMIN to make that call rather than just any other USER.

1 -https://prntscr.com/jhnlj3 (Resource API)
2- https://prntscr.com/jhnlwo  (Test Case)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your setup. You will have to provide more details.

You can mock a user for your testing. This will force to execute your test as a custom user with a specific role.

> [@WithMockUser(username="admin",roles={"USER","ADMIN"})](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/test-method.html#test-method-withmockuser)

You can also just pass your credentials to the AP, if you intent to call a API such as Restful. These credentials should preferable be memory only credentials such that you do not pollute your environment with test details.

Comment: i have mocked user using @WithMockUser already , but it didn't help , tried passing credentials to the API too , but that too isn't helping  me out . @PreAuthorize() doesn't works . 
Tried a lot options but SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication(); always return null , which leads to failing of my test case coz of NULLPOINTER exception.

Comment: Can you update your question and provide me some more implementation details?

Comment: I see that you are using `@PreAuthorize`. Did you remember to turn this feature on? `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)`

Comment: i have attached 2 images , can u check and tell me ?

Comment: You will have to post your code as code snippets and not images. This is the proper way to use stackoverflow. You need to make it easy for people who might have similar questions like you.